# What are the automated bat identification (acoustics) tools available?

Tags: automated-detection, pam, bats

Bat acoustics research started as early as the 1970s. Many researchers and manufacturers have developed automated bat detectors. These tools are effective ways to assess an ecological system. [Kaleidoscope](https://www.wildlifeacoustics.com/products/kaleidoscope/automatic-bat-identification) has the functions of bat auto identification. What is the software/package available for bat identification through acoustics? What are their limitations? Is there any open-source solution to bat auto identification*?

Answer (score 11):

The grassroots [Bat-pi](http://www.bat-pi.eu/EN/software-EN.html) project has a list of software that you can use to analyze bat calls. Not all are automated, but they also provide references to get you started. They are EU-based.

*Software  (Freeware) for  bat call analysis*

- BatScope (Mac OS X). Databank, optical analysis, classification
- Raven Lite (Mac OS X, Windows) optical analysis
- Avisoft-SASLab Lite (Windows) optical analysis
- WaveSurfer (Windows) optical analysis
- BatClassify (Windows) analysis
- SeaWave Sound Emission Analyzer Wave edition (Windows) optical analysis
- BatExplorer Software (Windows) optical analysis

*Commercial Software*

- ecoObs GmbH: bcAdmin (Mac OS X). Databank, optical anaysis, classification, result mangement
- ecoObs GmbH: bcAnalyze (Mac OS X). optical analysis, call examples
  Pettersson: BatSound (Windows) optical analysis,
- Avisoft: SASLab Pro  Bioacoustics Laboratory Software (Windows) optical analysis, classification
- Ravensoundsoftware: Raven pro (Mac OS X, Windows) optical analysis,
- Binaryacoustics: SCAN’R selection of bat calls by parameter filters
- Biotope: Sonochiro optical analysis, classification (rentable)
- Wildlifeacoustics: Kaleidoscope optical analysis, classification by selfmade classifiers

Comment: Batscope is also available for Windows (unfortunately no Linux)

Answer (score 7):

PAMGuard has recently been updated so it can be used more in terrestrial acoustics, with a focus on bats. [Here](https://github.com/macster110/PAMGuard_resources/tree/main/deep_learning) is a tutorial which demonstrates how to process acoustic data (e.g. data collected on an [AudioMoth](https://www.openacousticdevices.info/audiomoth)) to automatically detect bat calls and then utilise a deep learning model to classify the calls to species.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any personal experience, but the 'Tadarida' toolkit comes to mind. Here's [the paper link](https://openresearchsoftware.metajnl.com/article/10.5334/jors.154/) and here's [the repository](https://github.com/YvesBas/Tadarida-C).

While the tool itself is a generic classification and training tool, the paper highlights its use in various acoustic bat species surveys.