# Are there available raw model weights for bat detector / classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, automated-detection, classifier, bats

I will need to analyze some soundscape data from Norway and it is likely that bats are present in the area. I was wondering if there was any available model trained for bat detection or ideally bat classification. I am aware of [BatDetective](https://github.com/macaodha/batdetect) but the github repository only provide the training / validation data. While it would be possible to retrain a model with the data provided on the BatDetective github, I would rather use a state-of-the-art bat detector / classifier.

To be clear I am not looking for a software such as mentioned in [this post](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/469/what-are-the-automated-bat-identification-acoustics-tools-available) but I am rather interested in the raw model weights so I can have a greater coding flexibility.

Comment: Could you update with what geographic region you're looking at?

Comment: I edited and added that the soundscape data comes from Norway. However, any model would be helpful!

Comment: @BenjaminCretois Please edit the main title so it is a specific question. As it stands, your title is a short phrase that doesn't let readers know what information you're looking for. See guide for: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this fits your desire for a "state-of-the-art" detector, but it looks like BatDetective actually does have model weights available, just a bit hidden. If you download the "data" zip file from [this website](http://visual.cs.ucl.ac.uk/pubs/batDetective/). There is a Pickle'd model "test_set_bulgaria.mod" within the models folder. There are also two sets of model weights saved [here](https://github.com/macaodha/batdetect/tree/master/bat_eval/models) as .npy files.

If you have some of your own labeled training data then I would guess that one of those weights will probably be a decent starting place, or at least better than starting from scratch.

Comment: Well spotted Taiki!